# How to keep the radio button checked when paginating in laravel paginate

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-pagination

When I searched details based on 'Status', it's searching properly and keeping checked. But problem is, when I go to next page by clicking pagination number then checked radio button removed. I want to keep searched radio button be checked after clicking the paginate number. Would you please someone help me to solve this problem?

Here is my search form and one screenshot bellow-

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
   <div class="form-group">
       <label class="filter-col" for="pref-search">Search:</label>
       <input type="text" name="keyword" class="form-control1" value="{{ ($keyword) ? $keyword : '' }}" placeholder="Search by keyword" id="pref-search">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="radio" class="filter-col">Status:</label>
       <div class="col-sm-8 form-control1">
       <div class="radio-inline">
         <label>
         <input name="status" {{ ($cstatus == '')  ? 'checked="checked"' : '' }} type="radio" value="">
         All</label>
       </div>
       <div class="radio-inline">
         <label>
         <input name="status" {{ ($cstatus == 'open')  ? 'checked="checked"' : '' }} type="radio" value="open">
       Open</label>
       </div>
       <div class="radio-inline">
         <label>
         <input name="status" {{ ($cstatus == 'closed')  ? 'checked="checked"' : '' }} type="radio" value="closed">
          Closed</label>
       </div>                                    
      </div>                                
   </div>
   <div class="form-group" style="float: right;">
     <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question, but from what I understand, have you tried using `->append()` to you pagination function? `Model::paginate(10)->appends( $request->input() );`. That will add your current query string to your pagination urls.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. It is what I expected.

Comment: You're welcome! You can check the other question to have alternative answers.